# Blank rows on 2 TableViewController with data from one Viewcontroller in the other viewcontroller

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, uitableview

I have 2 `UITableViewController`s in my project.
The problem I am having is that I am getting blank cell entries in the `tableView` opposite to the `tableView` where the data is entered.

I can't seem to figure out why this is the case.
It's creating blank rows in this `tableView` even though the information is from the other `UITableViewController`.

Here's the main `tableView` part from the one of the 2 `UITableViewController`s:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"number of addedSpaceObjects %lu",(unsigned long)[self.diaryoptions count]);

    // Return the number of sections.
    return 1;        
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of sections %ld",(long)section);

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    return [self.diaryoptions count];
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentification = @"Cell";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentification 
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    Data2 *diary = [self.diaryoptions objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
    cell.textLabel.text = diary.diaryname;
    cell.detailTextLabel.text = diary.diaryWeight;

    return cell;  
}
```

And from other `UITableViewController`:

```
- (NSInteger)numberOfSectionsInTableView:(UITableView *)tableView
{
    NSLog(@"number of addedSpaceObjects %lu",(unsigned long)[self.addedSpaceObjects count]);

    // Return the number of sections.
    if ([self.addedSpaceObjects count]) {
        return 2;
    }
    else {
        return 1;
    }
}

- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSLog(@"number of sections %ld",(long)section);

    // Return the number of rows in the section.
    if (section == 1) {
        return [self.addedSpaceObjects count];
    }
    else {
        return [self.recipes count];
    }
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    static NSString *CellIdentification = @"Josh";
    UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentification 
                                                            forIndexPath:indexPath];

    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        Data *recipe = [self.addedSpaceObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = recipe.name;
    }
    else {
        // Configure the cell...
        Data *recipe = [self.recipes objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = recipe.name;
    }
    return cell;
}
```

Here is the full project on GitHub.  https://github.com/josher32/Plant-Diet

Appreciate any help anyone can offer!

Comment: Are you Getting blank cell on both Tableviews?

Comment: you need to elaborate more on `diaryoptions` and `addedSpaceObjects`, how you're 'entering' data in the first `UITableViewController`, how you're manipulating `addedSpaceObjects` and whether you're atleast getting the proper number of rows in both cases.

Comment: I am using NSUserDictionaries to enter the data but with 2 separate storage keys.  Yes both view controllers are showing blank cells in the places the other view controller has an entry.  Should I post the entire .m file for both view controllers?

Comment: The full project is at the following GitHub website: https://github.com/josher32/Plant-Diet

Comment: Sorry I meant to say I am using NSUserDefaults not dictionaries above to enter the data from another view controller but with 2 separate storage keys.

Comment: By `NewsTableViewController.m` you meant `RecipesTableTableViewController.m`... right? btw... what is one supposed to look out for? Since you've shared your project, you might as well specify the steps to re-create your problem and I've have a go at it.

Comment: ok, i see the problem... \*whistle\* this is gonna take me some time to answer :|

Comment: Yes RecipesTableTableViewController.m. And DiaryTableViewController are the conflicting ones where each other's blank cells are showing up.. Sure do appreciate the help I've been trying to figure this out for over a month but I'm still a beginner programmer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, so I checked out the app and I'll try my best to explain the problem as precisely as I can to cover it adequately.

Firstly, the classes in question are:

1. `RecipesTableTableViewController`

   - `AddRecipeViewController`
   - `Data`
2. `DiaryTableViewController`

   - `AddDiaryViewController`
   - `Data2`

Secondly, we'll need to look into your

```
#define ADDED_SPACE_OBJECTS2 @"Added Space Objects Array"
```

---

### `AddRecipeViewController`

So... `AddRecipeViewController` basically creates a `Data` object that is kept in an array and eventually stored in `NSUserDefaults` under the key name `Added Space Objects Array`.

Great!! So you now have got recipe related stuff in some `Data` object.

---

### `AddDiaryViewController`

Same thing here.
`AddDiaryViewController` creates a `Data2` object that is eventually stored in `NSUserDefaults` under the **same** key name `Added Space Objects Array`.
**But** before storing this, you're taking the old value of the key `Added Space Objects Array`, which is an array, and adding a new object to it before placing it back into `NSUserDefaults`.

But now... this array will now have a combination of `Data` as well as `Data2` objects!

### `RecipesTableTableViewController`

When we come here, things get real.

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    //...
    NSArray *myRecipeAsPropertyLists = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] arrayForKey:ADDED_SPACE_OBJECTS_KEY];
    for (NSDictionary *dictionary in myRecipeAsPropertyLists) {
        Data *spaceObject = [self spaceObjectForDictionary:dictionary];
        [self.addedSpaceObjects addObject:spaceObject];
    }
}
```

Since we already realized that `self.addedSpaceObjects` can contain `Data` as well as `Data2` objects, in the case when`dictionary` is containing stuff specific to type `Data2`, `spaceObjectForDictionary` will not be able to translate it properly to the required `Data` object.

We're expecting `name`, `title`, `ingredients`, `directions` but we're getting `diaryentry`, `diaryname`,`diaryWeight`.

So (in this scenario):

1. The values of `name`, `title`, `ingredients`, `directions` will be `nil`
2. The section-row count will be incorrect because it will give count of both `Data` as well as `Data2` objects (and we don't care about `Data2` objects in the `RecipesTableTableViewController` class... *right?... well anyways, I assumed*)

---

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{       
    //... 
    if (indexPath.section == 1) {
        Data *recipe = [self.addedSpaceObjects objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
        cell.textLabel.text = recipe.name;
    }
    //...
}
```

We see `recipe.name` is `nil`, for some `indexPath`s, ergo blank rows and vice versa in `DiaryTableViewController`.

---

## Solution:

*Firstly, I wouldn't recommend `NSUserDefaults` for your purposes but anyways...*

Basically, **don't** use a single `@"Added Space Objects Array"` key for your `NSUserDefaults` stuff.

I'd suggest you use 2 separate keys.

```
//replace
//#define ADDED_SPACE_OBJECTS2 @"Added Space Objects Array"
//with
#define ADDED_SPACE_OBJECTS2 @"RecipeEntries" //in RecipesTableTableViewController
//and
#define ADDED_SPACE_OBJECTS2 @"DiaryEntries" //in DiaryTableViewController
```

Basically, segregate the entries instead of mixing them up under a single key name.
This seems like the quickest way to solve your problem without changing your logic.

Comment: Thanks so much!!! That fixed my problem finally!  Can't believe I didn't think of that!